# How to get the link of a video from a facebook post (graph api)

Tags: php, facebook, object, facebook-graph-api

I want to embed videos on an external website so I need the link of the actual video. Is there a way to get that from the `posts` object?

I am currently looping some info from `posts` so it would be great if I could retrieve the videolink of a post somehow, I know how to get the image from a post, but there is nothing in their docs about videos. Only a different object called `videos` which just show all videos from a page. How can I combine the two so I can use the data from field `embed_html` in `posts`? Is that even possible?

Part of the `posts` object:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2017-09-12T20:58:21+0000",
         "message": "Vandaag bij Vivienne Westwood Boutique Amsterdam de lichtreclame gemonteerd. Mooi project om te mogen doen.\n\u2705  maatwerk\n\u2705  kwaliteit\n\u2705  betaalbaar\n\ud83d\udc4b  Benieuwd naar de kosten? We helpen je graag!\n- Reclame & Internet - #ontwerp > #productie > #montage",
         "id": "367712570004555_1287302444712225"
      },
```

Part of the `video` object:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "embed_html": "\u003Ciframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.facebook.com\u00252Fwebsite\u00252Fvideos\u00252F1287302444712225\u00252F&width=1280\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\"true\" allowFullScreen=\"true\">\u003C/iframe>",
         "permalink_url": "/website/videos/1287302444712225/",
         "id": "1287302444712225"
      },
```

They are both in different objects, how can I use them both in one looped element (a box with video/image and a description, that I already made so that is not my question)?

I see the post id and the video id are kinda similar, except I need to explode the post id on the underscore and compare the last part of the id (if I'm correct).

Am I overthinking this and is it way simpler or..?

Comment: Have you considered using Embedded Videos plugin? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/

Comment: I dont see how that would make a difference, I still need to loop the videos. @Bangdel